# Unable to update "Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update"

Tags: boot, 22.10

New Ubuntu 22.10 install.  GUI update shows "Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update 77-217". When update is attempted (from GUI)  error is displayed "Unable to update "Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update": failed to write data to efivarfs: Error writing to file descriptor: Invalid argument"

When update attempted with "fwupdmgr update" then error is: "failed to write data to efivarfs: Error writing to file descriptor: Invalid argument"

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue, too! And we are not the only ones.

Unfortunately, according to [this Github issue](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/5643) and [the Wiki](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/LVFS-Triaged-Issue:-dbx-efivarfs-IO-error) it looks like a hardware/firmware issue that only a firmware upgrade can fix.